# Count is not working in trigger using condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Hi could you please suggest I am trying to check if count =2 
When  Condition meet (DA.matr_ID = '478') or (DA.matr_ID = '40') then
insert into table, but in any condition like   (DA.matr_ID = '479') it insert the data which is wrong

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEVICE_TMP_TR
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES_TMP
  REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pragma autonomous_transaction;
V_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
     INTO V_COUNT  
  FROM DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES_TMP DA 
  WHERE DA.DVS_ID = :new.DVS_ID 
   AND (DA.matr_ID = '40' or DA.matr_ID = '478');

  IF V_COUNT = 2 THEN
    INSERT Into APP_DELETED_TMP    
      (sdmid,appid,devis,des_nr,creation_date,creation_user,ant_id) 
    VALUES
      ('121213', '23', '45','63',SYSDATE,'hhdhSH',21);
    COMMIT;
  ELSE 
    RETURN;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: first off, looks like you are missing a right parenthesis in the AND clause, so this should not even compile.

Comment: It's by mistake corrected now, trigger compiling I already checked

Comment: Are you clearing the content of DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES_TMP between tests?

Comment: You are using `pragma autonomous_transaction`, presumably so you can query the table which owns the trigger without Oracle hurling a mutating table exception. However, this means your query excludes from consideration whatever data you have changed **in the current transaction**. So that might be one cause of  unexpected results. If that explanation doesn't satisfy you please post a reproducible test case with data structures, sample data and update statements which reproduce the issue.